# Change label color Y and X axis chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have tried to change to change the chart label colour to white for the Y and X axis. I tried to add the code with fontColour from other threads here on stackoverflow but won't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
  var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
  var lineChartData = {
    labels : ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: 'My First dataset',
        fontColor : '#fff' ,
        backgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        borderColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBorderColor : '#fff',
        data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
      }
    ]
  }

  var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      fontColor: "white",
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
          beginAtZero: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          stepSize: Math.ceil(250 / 5),
          max: 250
        }
      }]
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your `options` block looks OK and should change the label colour, but you aren't actually including it when setting up your chart

Comment: Thanks! :D Worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the *options* object to **`options`** property, when constructing the chart.

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
};
var lineChartData = {
   labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
   datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      fontColor: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
   }]
}

var options = {
   responsive: true,
   maintainAspectRatio: false,
   legend: {
      fontColor: "white",
   },
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            fontColor: "white",
         }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            fontColor: "white",
            beginAtZero: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 5,
            stepSize: Math.ceil(250 / 5),
            max: 250
         }
      }]
   }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: lineChartData,
   options: options //<- assign this
});
```

```css
canvas { background: #111 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas-1"></canvas>
```